# How I can detect changes in Number variables?

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to `console.log()` when a variable changed. JavaScript basically doesn't provide watchers for variables. So I wonder how to do it.

For objects and arrays, I can use Proxy, like this:

```
let proxy = new Proxy(arr, {
    deleteProperty: function(target, property) {
        console.log("Deleted %s", property);
        return true;
    },
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver) {
        target[property] = value;
        console.log("Set %s to %o", property, value);
        return true;
    }
});
```

But I have no idea what to do with Numbers. How to make them observable?

Comment: You cannot observe on primitive values. There are just.... values. You will need an object/function wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot observe on primitive values. They are just values. You will need an object/function wrapper. One simple trick is to set and get to the same key regardless of the key you specify, which essentially takes the objectness out of the object, it feels like a primitive to use.

```js
const number = new Proxy({ value : 5 }, {
  set: (obj, prop, value, receiver)  => { console.log('value set');  obj.value = value; return true },
  get: (obj, prop) =>  { console.log('value get');  return obj.value}
})

number.foo = 10

console.log(number.bar)
```